# How do I get a Date to store as a Date in MongoDB instead of an Int64?

Tags: mongodb, scala, date, mongodb-scala

I'm using the new MongoDB Scala Driver.  When I store a java.util.Date, it is being stored in MongoDB as an Int64 instead of a MongoDB Date.  I have some code that looks like this:

```
implicit val writer = new Writes[Forecast] {
  def writes(x: Forecast): JsValue = {
    Json.obj(
      // ...
      "issueDateTime" -> x.issueDateTime // which is a java.util.Date
      // ...
    )
  }
}
```

but what ends up in MongoDB is an Int64, not a Date.  How do I get a Date into MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest [MongoDB Scala Driver v1.1](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.1/).
Instead of using the Json.obj to build your document, try using [Document](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/scaladoc/index.html#org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.mutable.Document) class.

The [BsonTransformer](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/scala/org/mongodb/scala/bson/BsonTransformer.scala#L110) will transform [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to [BsonDateTime](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/scaladoc/?_ga=1.102372549.535922586.1448855826#org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonDateTime$)

For example:

```
val newdate = new Date()
val doc: Document = Document("test" -> newdate)
collection.insertOne(doc).results()
```

Will result in :

```
{  "_id" : ObjectId("56665bf619a63d9e538b2851"), 
    "test" : ISODate("2015-12-08T04:26:29.999Z") 
}
```

Hope that helps.