# Scala Mongo Query Find Filter generates Date as Long

Tags: mongodb, scala, date, find, range

In Mongo,

```
"org.mongodb.scala"        %% "mongo-scala-driver"       % "2.1.0",
```

I have this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5aeb1cc6f99d155c16478c96"), 
"userId" : "2c48bc64-76cd-41b0-88af-b8dfea667960", 
"eventAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T14:29:25.964Z"), 
"activity" : { "userAltId" : null,
               ...
               "completedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-26T04:00:00Z"),
               ...
 }
```

In my Mongo shell, when I run this query

```
> db.getCollection('wwactivities').find({ userId: "2c48bc64-76cd-41b0-88af-b8dfea667960" , "activity.completedAt": {$lte: ISODate("2018-04-26T23:59:59Z")}, "activity.completedAt": {$gte: ISODate("2018-04-26T00:00:00Z")}})
```

I get the correct resultset:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aeb1cc6f99d155c16478c96"), "userId" : "2c48bc64-76cd-41b0-88af-b8dfea667960", "eventAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T14:29:25.964Z"), "activity" : { 
"userAltId" : null, ...
"completedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-26T04:00:00Z"), ... 
} }
```

In when I try to generate the query in scala code, and I use Scala-Mongo Filters like this:

```
val x = and( equal("userId", activityKey.userId), lt("activity.completedAt", atEndOfDay(toDate)), gt("activity.completedAt", atStartOfDay(fromDate)))

def atStartOfDay( date: Date ) = {
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.setTime(date)
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
cal.getTime()
```

}

Or explicitly like this:

```
val x = Document("activity.completedAt" -> Document("$gt" -> atStartOfDay(fromDate), "$lt" -> atEndOfDay(toDate)))
  println( s"q: ${document.toJson()}")
```

In both cases, the println yields:

```
q: { "activity.completedAt" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : 1524715200000 }, "$lt" : { "$date" : 1524715200000 } } }
```

When I run

```
myCollection.find(x)
```

The result set is empty.

So in a nutshell, I write a query using ISODate in the Mongo shell and it works and returns the correct Document.  However when I generate the query in Scala, it represents the date fields as int64 and the resultset is empty.

It looks like the generated document from the Filter represents the java.util.Date as a Long in the query.

```
scala> new Date(1524715200000L)
res74: java.util.Date = Thu Apr 26 00:00:00 EDT 2018

scala> new Date(1524801599999L)

res75: java.util.Date = Thu Apr 26 23:59:59 EDT 2018
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the driver? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140698/how-do-i-get-a-date-to-store-as-a-date-in-mongodb-instead-of-an-int64

Comment: Thank @dnickless,I was using 2.1.0.
I found that using the aggregates way worked.
Like this:
activityCollection
            .aggregate(
          List(
            filter(equal("userId", activityKey.userId)),
            filter(gte("activity.completedAt", atStartOfDay(fromDate))),
            filter(lte("activity.completedAt", atEndOfDay(toDate)))
          )
        )